# Date status function to displays Overdue, Due Later and Due Soon

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am currently working on function in Excel that will display the status of an activity based on the due date provided.

This function would display:
"Overdue" if Today()> Due Date;
"Due Soon" If the Due date was within one week
"Due Later" if Today() < Due Date +7

[image: Image of the table for reference]

Below is an example of what I was able to muster up:

```
Function Status_of_Date()

If Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Due_Date").Value < Date Then
    Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Date_Status").Value = "Overdue" 'overdue

ElseIf Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Due_Date").Value < 7 + Date Then
    Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Date_Status").Value = "Due Later" ' Due Soon

ElseIf Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Due_Date").Value > 7 + Date Then
    Sheets("Issue_Log").Range("Date_Status").Value = "Due Later" ' Due Later

Else
End If
End Function
```

Comment: And.....What is your question/problem?

Comment: I think I see the issue: On the first `ElseIf`, the text string doesn't match the comment. Don't use obvious comments - they quickly become out of date. Oh, and there's an extra `Else` right before the `End If`.

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula, is vba really needed?

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to test and assign single values to a multi-cell range.  you will need to loop and test each individual cell in the range and put the value in each individual cell.  It will not do it automatically.

Comment: How does the function know what row to look at? Also, this looks like a table/`ListObject` - naming and then dereferencing the column ranges seems rather wasteful. Just use a table formula, e.g. `=IF([Due Date] < TODAY(), "Overdue", IF([Due Date] < TODAY()+7, "Due Soon", IF([Due Date] >= TODAY()+7, "Due Later", "")))` ...no need for any code here.

Comment: Or better, have a column that counts the number of days until the due date; `=IF([Due Date]-TODAY()<0,-1,[Due Date]-TODAY())`, and then have a simple vlookup (with the last parameter being `True`) over another table, sorted, that gives you the "status" for a given number of days. That way you can add more statuses and change any of them on a whim, without needing to change any code or the lookup formula.

Comment: or `=IFERROR(INDEX({Due Soon","Due Later"},MIN(INT(([@Due Date]-Today())/7)+1,2)),"OVERDUE")`

Comment: Or a simple cell formula of `=[Due Date] - [Opened Date]` in the `[Date Status]` column, then use conditional highlighting to make >7 = Green, >0 AND <8 Yellow, <=0 Red

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions! I'm actually a petroleum engineer who isn't the best at VBA/formulas etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Codeless Solution

Add a column to your table, to count the days left - since anything negative is overdue anyway, make all negatives `-1`:

[image]

Use a table formula to calculate it:

```
=IF([@[Due Date]]-TODAY()<0,-1,[@[Due Date]]-TODAY())
```

Next, have another table to hold the status given a number of days:

[image]

Since you have 3 statuses, and they're really *ranges* of values, to achieve the values you're after you'll need:

- A row with `-1` for everything `Overdue`
- A row with `0` for everything due `Soon`
- A row with `7` for everything due `Later`

Now your "Date Status" column can be a simple `VLOOKUP` formula:

[image]

Again, a table formula is used; note the "approximate match" last parameter:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Days],tblStatusLookup,2,TRUE)
```

Adjust `tblStatusLookup` to whatever you've named your lookup table.

*Look 'ma, not a single line of code!*

Then you can hide the [Days] column if you don't need it shown, and the lookup table can be anywhere you want - and if the thresholds need to change, or if new statuses need to be added, you just tweak the lookup table (important: keep the [Days] sorted ascending, that's how *approximate match* VLOOKUP works!)

---

#### Bugs in OP

Your function needs to know what row to work with. That should be a parameter; change the *signature* to accept one - or even better, change it to accept a `DueDate` parameter - then you simply don't need to care about anything other than the date you're given:

```
Public Function GetDateStatus(ByVal dueDate As Date) As String
    If dueDate - Date < 0 Then
        GetDateStatus = "Overdue"
    ElseIf dueDate - Date < 7 Then
        GetDateStatus = "Due Soon"
    Else
        GetDateStatus = "Due Later"
    End If
End function
```

And then in your table the formula would be:

```
=GetDateStatus(@[Due Date])
```

No need to be bothered with ranges and the nitty-gritty details of how and where every value is coming from - code gets much, much simpler when you work at the right abstraction level!

Note that a worksheet function is not allowed to change other cells' values: it *calculates* a value.

Comment: You could also put `-1E+99` in for the `-1` in the lookup table and just do the VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP([@[Due Date]]-TODAY(),tblStatusLookup,2,TRUE)` and not add the days column.

Comment: @ScottCraner good point... I guess I just like having the working/intermediate values in sight =)

Comment: To each his/her own.  I like clean lines.  Either way is good.